# Can I run a mix of static addressing and NAT?

Tags: networking, dhcp, nat

Let's say that an ISP offers a plan with 5 static IP addresses, but I have more than 5 devices, many of which (such as a networked printer, for instance) I do not want or need to have a static IP address.

So the topography I'm planning goes something like:

```
ISP -> Router -> Switch -> Computer (static address)
                        -> Computer (static address)
                        -> Printer (DHCP/NAT)
                        -> Tv (DHCP/NAT)
                        -> (...)

              -> Wireless Devices (DHCP/NAT)
```

Generally speaking, is it possible to run a network like that?  If not, then what sort of setup do I need so that I can assign static addresses just to the things that need them, and use DHCP/NAT for everything else?

Also, what internal networking devices will consume a static IP address?  I'm pretty sure the router will, correct?  Does the switch also?

Comment: This is possible, but probably not with a consumer-grade router.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is one static address for the router which will NAT the other connections. You can configure every other device via DHCP or an internal static address of your choosing. The switch unless it is a layer 3 device will not require an address of its own and serves only to interconnect your internal hardware.

Answer (score 0):

that's possible.

but it is a function available only for enterprise routers or proxy servers.. it's called one to one nat (one public ip > one private ip).

this function is used only for specific purposes (servers with many services and with domain name associated)

however, this kind of configuration is not efficient.. you use an entire ip (65k ports) for one pc... I think it's better to think at a different structure (like virtual servers for needed services for each computer in the network).